Can you translate these Mayan glyphs?
Translate the following 13 Mayan glyphs shown on the following page that are ordered in the traditional block configuration to form a three sentence story. This text was created by me and is not found anywhere in the realm of Classic Maya literature.
Hint:

 Each Mayan glyph encodes a single word that is broken down into several (C)V phonetic subglyphs. However, the actual Classic Mayan syllable structure is (C)V(C). Research the nature of the script, drop the extra vowels used only in writing, transcribe the glottalized vowels correctly, and then obtain the actual text in Classic Maya. When translating the actual Classic Maya text, make sure to take note of prefixes and suffixes that are incorporated into words, which may consist of only a single consonant.


